# CURL alternative in Python

Tags: python, curl

I have a cURL call that I use in PHP:

```bash
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/xml' -u login:key "https://app.streamsend.com/emails"
```

I need a way to do the same thing in Python. Is there an alternative to cURL in Python? I know of urllib but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: You can try [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net)

Comment: urllib2 is a widely used package for this kind of work.

Comment: Even better:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: The above is a link for a great library to do simple http `requests` in python (available to install via easy_install or pip in PyPi).  The name/URL is slightly confusing -- at first I almost thought this was a wishlist request for a better `urllib2`, instead `requests` a very intuitive easy to use pythonic library `sudo easy_install requests` or `sudo pip install requests`.

Comment: [Python Requests vs PyCurl Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461995/python-requests-vs-pycurl-performance) You decent on your requirement

Comment: Paste your command into https://curlconverter.com/python/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
import urllib2

manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
manager.add_password(None, 'https://app.streamsend.com/emails', 'login', 'key')
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(manager)

director = urllib2.OpenerDirector()
director.add_handler(handler)

req = urllib2.Request('https://app.streamsend.com/emails', headers = {'Accept' : 'application/xml'})

result = director.open(req)
# result.read() will contain the data
# result.info() will contain the HTTP headers

# To get say the content-length header
length = result.info()['Content-Length']
```

Your cURL call using urllib2 instead. Completely untested.

Comment: It's nice to compare this with the answer right below and see how far Python has progressed over the past four years

Answer (score 136):

You can use the [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library. Install it with

```bash
pip install requests
```

You can find its documentation at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Requests is the latest and greatest! It smokes and burns clumsy urllib2, i wish requests becomes standard HTTP Client for python incoming 3.x versions

Comment: When I switched to using requests I never looked back to using urllib2 directly anymore.  The built-in JSON decoding is handy as well.  No need to manually load the body with json if the appropriate content-type is set.

Comment: Requests is so simple.  I was even able to create a custom authentication scheme in a few minutes.  urllib2 is super-annoying.

Comment: For those in 2023 looking for a modern alternative to the aging `requests` (same human-friendly API, but not feature-frozen, and keeping up with modern developments like  `async`, HTTP 2, and so on) I currently recommend `httpx`.

Answer (score 36):

Here's a simple example using urllib2 that does a basic authentication against GitHub's API.

```
import urllib2

u='username'
p='userpass'
url='https://api.github.com/users/username'

# simple wrapper function to encode the username & pass
def encodeUserData(user, password):
    return "Basic " + (user + ":" + password).encode("base64").rstrip()

# create the request object and set some headers
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.add_header('Authorization', encodeUserData(u, p))
# make the request and print the results
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.read()
```

Furthermore if you wrap this in a script and run it from a terminal you can pipe the response string to 'mjson.tool' to enable pretty printing.

```
>> basicAuth.py | python -mjson.tool
```

One last thing to note, urllib2 only supports GET & POST requests.
 
If you need to use other HTTP verbs like DELETE, PUT, etc you'll probably want to take a look at [PYCURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: *Why was this voted down?* Perhaps because you wrote PYCURL instead of PycURL :D

Answer (score 20):

If you are using a command to just call curl like that, you can do the same thing in Python with `subprocess`. Example:

```
subprocess.call(['curl', '-i', '-H', '"Accept: application/xml"', '-u', 'login:key', '"https://app.streamsend.com/emails"'])
```

Or you could try [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) if you want to have it as a more structured api like what PHP has.

Comment: No. The cURL call is part of a program. If you could post the code that does the exact same thing being done in the curl call above, that would be great.

Comment: Added an example of what I meant by using subprocess based on your question, but I'm guessing you're looking for something more like PycURL.

Comment: I know this is older, but PycURL is pretty low level for most usages of cURL in my opinion.  Even the PHP implementation of cURL is fairly low level.

Comment: I get "name error, name subprocess not defined" after calling "python" from cmd and therefore being in the python env.

Comment: @Timo Did you `import subprocess`? The python repl environment is just like a python file, you have to import the other modules.

Answer (score 13):

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.tld/'
auth = ('username', 'password')

r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
print(r.content)
```

This is the simplest I've been able to get it.

Comment: This is the simplest answer! `urllib2` is overly complicated.

Answer (score 7):

Some example, how to use urllib for that things, with some sugar syntax. I know about requests and other libraries, but urllib is standard lib for python and doesn't require anything to be installed separately.

Python 2/3 compatible.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
  from urllib.request import HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm, HTTPBasicAuthHandler, Request, build_opener
  from urllib.parse import urlencode
else:
  from urllib2 import HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm, HTTPBasicAuthHandler, Request, build_opener
  from urllib import urlencode


def curl(url, params=None, auth=None, req_type="GET", data=None, headers=None):
  post_req = ["POST", "PUT"]
  get_req = ["GET", "DELETE"]

  if params is not None:
    url += "?" + urlencode(params)

  if req_type not in post_req + get_req:
    raise IOError("Wrong request type \"%s\" passed" % req_type)

  _headers = {}
  handler_chain = []

  if auth is not None:
    manager = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    manager.add_password(None, url, auth["user"], auth["pass"])
    handler_chain.append(HTTPBasicAuthHandler(manager))

  if req_type in post_req and data is not None:
    _headers["Content-Length"] = len(data)

  if headers is not None:
    _headers.update(headers)

  director = build_opener(*handler_chain)

  if req_type in post_req:
    if sys.version_info.major == 3:
      _data = bytes(data, encoding='utf8')
    else:
      _data = bytes(data)

    req = Request(url, headers=_headers, data=_data)
  else:
    req = Request(url, headers=_headers)

  req.get_method = lambda: req_type
  result = director.open(req)

  return {
    "httpcode": result.code,
    "headers": result.info(),
    "content": result.read()
  }


"""
Usage example:
"""

Post data:
  curl("http://127.0.0.1/", req_type="POST", data='cascac')

Pass arguments (http://127.0.0.1/?q=show):
  curl("http://127.0.0.1/", params={'q': 'show'}, req_type="POST", data='cascac')

HTTP Authorization:
  curl("http://127.0.0.1/secure_data.txt", auth={"user": "username", "pass": "password"})
```

Function is not complete and possibly is not ideal, but shows a basic representation and concept to use. Additional things could be added or changed by taste.

12/08 update

[Here](https://github.com/hapylestat/apputils/blob/master/src/modules/apputils/curl/__init__.py) is a GitHub link to live updated source.
Currently supporting:

- authorization
- CRUD compatible
- automatic charset detection
- automatic encoding(compression) detection

Answer (score 4):

If it's running all of the above from the command line that you're looking for, then I'd recommend [***HTTPie***](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie). It is a fantastic cURL alternative and is *super easy* and *convenient* to use (and customize).

Here's is its *(succinct and precise)* description from GitHub;

> HTTPie (pronounced aych-tee-tee-pie) is a command line HTTP client.
>   Its goal is to make CLI interaction with web services as
>   human-friendly as possible.
>
> It provides a simple http command that allows for sending arbitrary
>   HTTP requests using a simple and natural syntax, and displays
>   colorized output. HTTPie can be used for testing, debugging, and
>   generally interacting with HTTP servers.

---

The documentation around ***[authentication](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#authentication)*** should give you enough pointers to solve your problem(s). Of course, all of the answers above are accurate as well, and provide different ways of accomplishing the same task.

---

Just so you do NOT have to move away from Stack Overflow, here's what it offers in a nutshell.

```html
Basic auth:

$ http -a username:password example.org
Digest auth:

$ http --auth-type=digest -a username:password example.org
With password prompt:

$ http -a username example.org
```

Comment: maybe I didn't get it at all, but is it a Python module ? I guess it a shell/CLI tool, and I'm disapointed :'( it seemed to be so easy to use

Comment: @Alex - It is a Python module. The README on Github (https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) contains everything you need.

Comment: HTTPie is for making HTTP requests from Bash, not from Python. It might be implemented in Python, but the library it uses to actually make the requests [is Requests](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/community-and-support).