# What module to use in Python to do the same as cURL in Php?

Tags: python, curl

I'm a PHP programmer. What module can I use in Python to do the same that cURL does?

Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [CURL alternative in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at python's "[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)"

Answer (score 1):

you can do the same stuff with urllib2, pycurl hasn't been updated in a while, so I wouldn't recommend it. Especially on Windows. Always better to use a native module rather than a 3rd party plugin