# Write curl in python code

Tags: json, post, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CURL alternative in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python)

I'm trying to write a python snippet that returns a JSON response. With curl it works and look like this:

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' \
     -d '' http://example.com/postservice.get_notes
```

How could I write code in python that returns a JSON object as the curl command does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **exactly mimic** this you'll need [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

```
import pycurl
import StringIO 

buf = StringIO.StringIO()

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://example.com/postservice.get_notes')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept-Charset: UTF-8'])
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, '')
c.perform()

json = buf.getvalue()
buf.close()
```

**Note** here `content-type: application/json` is not a valid request header. So it's not needed.

Comment: Is this the best solution to do receive data from a web-service?

Comment: **Best** is a relative word.  So there is no *Best solution* unless you give any context or criteria.  The solution I provided best matches your command line implementation. Both uses the same library (curl). So they will run the same code at the back end.