# How to translate cURL to Python web request?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Sorry to ask such entry level question. I need to translate the following `cURL` into python language. I tried to use `requests` function, which failed. So could anyone give me some hints? Is it right to choose requests? Should I consider urllib?
Thanks!

cURL code:

```
$ curl -k -u 'key:secret_key' -X POST https://api.picloud.com/file/new/ -d name=your_file_name
```

My bad attempt:

```
r = requests.put('https://api.picloud.com/file/new/',auth=(api_key,api_secretkey),data={'name':'your_file_name'})
```

I got the following errors:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Do I need to encoded my key and secret key first?

Comment: Ypu need to use pycurl to exactly mimic the behavior. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470060/write-curl-in-python-code/10470126#10470126

Comment: The https certificate on the server is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your curl command, you have used the `-k/--insecure` option to disable SSL certificate verification.

If you want to also disable SSL certificate verification, you can add `verify=False` to your requests.put call (See [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)).

**But this is surely a bad idea from a security point of view**. You **must** verify peer certificate by providing adequate root CA certificates.

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'password'), verify=False)
```

Comment: While this might solve the original question, it's best to include a description so we know what is going on.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.