# Python web crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

Is there any python crawler which pulls out all the data from a webpage for ex: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/HTC+-+One+S+4G+Mobile+Phone+-+Gradient+Blue+%28T-Mobile%29/4980512.p?id=1218587135819&skuId=4980512&contract_desc=
In this page the customer review has two pages 1 and 2.I want to crawl t his url and get the content of both the pages. Is this possible with a python crawler.

Also does python crawler supports all  the modern GET/POST technologies

Comment: Instead you could see if Best Buy has a API that would work for you.

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/):

> Scrapy is a fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data mining to monitoring and automated testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to crawl a site, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python). If you only want to process some pages and analyze their content (meaning you know the URLs you want to process), try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), it allows you to do things like:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
for f in soup.findAll('form'):
    target_url = f['action']
    #do something with each one of the forms
```