# Call an external webservice from Python code

Tags: python, web-services, curl

Currently I am calling an external webservice from command line in Unix :

```
curl --cert externalcertificate.cer --data @SampleRequest.xml -v https://world-service-dev.intra.a.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1
```

I need to integrate this call in my python code . Then I will put retry logic and response validation around it , what is the optimal way of making this call ? Since its a one way SSL , I also need to make sure my web service call refers to the external server certificate kept on my server as well .

I could not use requests module of Python as it is not installed on the server, I tried using urllib2 but facing multiple issue related to ssl as it is a https call . 
 Now I am trying to call a sub process module : 
`subprocess.call(['curl', '-k', '-H' , 'content-type: application/soap+xml' ,'-d',  etree.tostring(tree), '-v' ,'"https://world-service-dev.intra.aexp.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1"'])`

But getting an error message :

`* Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (1) Protocol "https not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) to call that web service.

Comment: I think I can use 
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
but how do I handle the certificate part... how do I make sure I also pass the server certificate while making this call.

Comment: Sadly I do not have requests library installed on my python environment and I do not have permissions to install it as well since its QA environment . Is there any other module I can use ?

Comment: Have at look at the answers here, specifically this one  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2667545/3236133

Answer (score 0):

I had a an extra double quote in front of my URL that was causing this problem to happen , Here is the correct syntax `subprocess.call(['curl', '-k', '-i', '-H' , 'content-type: application/soap+xml' ,'-d',  etree.tostring(tree), '-v' ,'https://world-service-dev.intra.aexp.com:4414/worldservice/CLIC/CaseManagementService/V1'])`