# Curl error when downloading json object

Tags: python, json, bash, curl

getting the following error...

```
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
```

...when using the following command to curl a json file

```
curl -L -o commerce.json http://www.commerce.gov/data.json
```

Any advice? I'm not familiar with curl. Perhaps it's a timeout error. Is there anyway I can prevent that? I really need the file, and I am unable to download it from a browser (assuming too big a file).

I'm working from command line on Ubuntu. Would love, alternatively to curl, a python solution.

Comment: And why not read the documentation for curl that describes this?

Answer (score 2):

the error code 56 means the following, as described here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> 56 Failure in receiving network data.

you should use a **-v** to see what's happen.

I don't thnik that another tool fix the network error.

Never the less there is a example in plain python.

[CURL alternative in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use:

```
wget -O commerce.json http://www.commerce.gov/data.json
```

Otherwise, a Python solution to this would be:

First you will need to install the Python `wget` library, then you can use the code:

```
import wget
url = 'http://www.commerce.gov/data.json'

commercejson = wget.download(url)
```

This will download the `data.json` file to your local Python project directory.
The `data.json` file is currently 198MB, so curl may not be able to handle it very well.

**UPDATE: Compressed JSON download:**

To enable gzip compression, you can use the following to download gzipped version, which ends up being 19MB instead, which would be much more friendly to download.

```
wget -S --header="accept-encoding: gzip" -O commerce.json.gz http://www.commerce.gov/data.json
```

Then, once the gzipped json file is downloaded, run the below command to decompress it:

`gzip -d commerce.json.gz`

Comment: Does wget work for you? I get endless tries like so: 
--2016-09-01 18:41:59--  https://www.commerce.gov/sites/commerce.gov/files/data.json
Reusing existing connection to [www.commerce.gov]:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 206604792 (197M) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘commerce2.json’

commerce2.json      0%[             ] 127.67K   749KB/s    in 0.2s    

2016-09-01 18:42:59 (749 KB/s) - Read error at byte 130732/206604792 (Connection reset by peer). Retrying.

Comment: wget does work for me, but I have a very fast internet connection.

Comment: I updated my answer to enable gzip compression on the downloaded json data.