# Sending audio to user in Facebook messenger bot

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to send audio file to user in Facebook messenger bot using file upload.
Official documentation says you can do it through curl command in terminal.
This command works:

```
curl  \
  -F 'recipient={"id":user_id}' \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"audio", "payload":{}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@mymp3.mp3;type=audio/mp3' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

where ACCESS_TOKEN is my page's token, "mymp3.mp3" is the file I want to send.

Question - how do I do the same in python using requests library?

I tried this:

```
with open("mymp3.mp3", "rb") as o:
    payload = {
        'recipient': "{id: 1336677726453307}",
        'message': {'attachment': {'type': 'audio', 'payload':{}}},
        'filedata':o, 'type':'audio/mp3'
    }
    files = {'recipient': {'id': '1336677726453307'},'filedata':o}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3'}
    r = requests.post(fb_url, data=payload)
print r.text
```

I get this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Message cannot be empty, must provide valid attachment or text","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018034,"fbtrace_id":"E5d95+ILnf5"}}
```

Also, tried this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

m = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        'recipient': {'id': '1336677726453307'},
        'message': {'attachment': {'type': 'audio', 'payload':{}}},
        'filedata':(open("mymp3.mp3", "rb"), 'audio/mp3')
    }
)
headers = {'Content-Type': m.content_type}
r = requests.post(fb_url, data=m, headers=headers)
print r.text
```

I got this error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python

Comment: just the first 2 results on google ;)

Comment: what have you tried and what are your current issues ?

Comment: @Guillaume please check out edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it (big thanks to my colleague!)

```
fb_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages'
data = {
    'recipient': '{"id":1336677726453307}',
    'message': '{"attachment":{"type":"audio", "payload":{}}}'
}
files = {
    'filedata': ('mymp3.mp3', open("mymp3.mp3", "rb"), 'audio/mp3')}
params = {'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}
resp = requests.post(fb_url, params=params, data=data, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first attempt was near the goal, but you seem to struggle with the fileupload. 
You first need to understand what `curl` does; [curl documentation is here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Then do the same thing with requests; Documentation is [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.request).

From what I understand, you can try:

```
with open("mymp3.mp3", "rb") as finput:
    data = {
        'recipient': "{id: 1336677726453307}",
        'message': {'attachment': {'type': 'audio', 'payload':{}}},
    }
    #
    files = {'filedata': ('mymp3.mp3', finput, 'audio/mp3')}
    # BTW you can remove the ACCESS_TOKEN from fb_url and pass it as params instead
    params = {'access_token': 'ACCESS_TOKEN'}
    resp = requests.post(fb_url, params=params, data=data, files=files)

print r.text
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Message cannot be empty, must provide valid attachment or text","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018034,"fbtrace_id":"HTjHVPM0grB"}}